# How to find solutions for a system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve systems like the following. Sometimes such systems may (or not) have infinitely many solutions. When I use `Solve[]`, `Reduce[]`, or `FindInstance[]`, it only returns one solution. How do I get the parametrized family of solutions?

```
M = {{0.333772337085864`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {-0.269015187516268`, 0.576396171912669`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.646590179448633`, -0.759633299840529`, 
    0.195352090970338`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {-2.09766982862937`, 
    2.88389272360333`, -0.145578215127938`, 0.248036249954749`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {2.42090665808053`, -3.26729259906371`, 
    0.693620968176017`, -0.165976259593602`, 0.822430222180933`, 
    0.`}, {-3.1947322051344`, 3.97955896726582`, -0.850693911651965`, 
    0.190456590870281`, -0.751458473262052`, 0.813434515956156`}};
n = Dimensions[M][[1]];
X = Array[x, n]; 
 u = ConstantArray[1, n];
Eqs = {Transpose[X] . M . (M . u) == 1/6, Transpose[X] . M . u == 1/2,
    Transpose[X] . (M . u)^2 == 1/3,  Transpose[X] . u == 1};
Reduce[Eqs]
Solve[Eqs]
```

Comment: You have four equations and six variables. Of course you will obtain solutions of the form e.g. $x_3=f(x_1,x_2)$. What alternative do you seek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize Bob's answer, AFAICS, since `Rationalize[#, 0]` doesn't really affect anything beyond a negligible amount of round-off error:

> Your code already works.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

M = {{0.333772337085864`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {-0.269015187516268`, 
     0.576396171912669`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
     0.`}, {0.646590179448633`, -0.759633299840529`, 0.195352090970338`, 0.`, 
     0.`, 0.`}, {-2.09766982862937`, 2.88389272360333`, -0.145578215127938`, 
     0.248036249954749`, 0.`, 0.`}, {2.42090665808053`, -3.26729259906371`, 
     0.693620968176017`, -0.165976259593602`, 0.822430222180933`, 
     0.`}, {-3.1947322051344`, 3.97955896726582`, -0.850693911651965`, 
     0.190456590870281`, -0.751458473262052`, 0.813434515956156`}} // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;
n = Dimensions[M][[1]];
X = Array[x, n];
u = ConstantArray[1, n];

Eqs = {Transpose[X] . M . (M . u) == 1/6, Transpose[X] . M . u == 1/2, 
    Transpose[X] . (M . u)^2 == 1/3, Transpose[X] . u == 1} // Simplify;

sol = Solve[Eqs] /. r_Rational :> N[r]

(* {{x[3] -> 0.208767 + 2.19681 x[1] + 1.47089 x[2], 
     x[4] -> 0.270082 - 0.264499 x[1] - 0.151315 x[2], 
     x[5] -> 0.459035 + 0.843625 x[1] + 0.437607 x[2], 
     x[6] -> 0.0621156 - 3.77593 x[1] - 2.75719 x[2]}} *)
```

The solutions are parameterized in terms of the arbitrary values for `x[1]` and `x[2]`